# Strategy exit limit is not being triggered correctly because of calc_on_order_fills

Tags: pine-script

the purpose of leaving calc_on_order_fills true is that I want it to exit the trade if the target or stop is hit during the current candles.

But in practice, when this happens, whenever it is to exit profit, it exits at the maximum of the candlestick in which it entered the trade, instead of exiting the target, and when the stop is reached, even if it is in the same candle, the stop is triggered correctly, it's as if the stop was set correctly, and the limit set
at the maximum of the entry candle

but it's weird because if you set calc_on_order_fills to false it's always calculating the values correctly

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Stochastic Slow Bar Strategy",initial_capital=100000, shorttitle="Stoch - 1 Buy", format=format.price, precision=2,overlay=true,calc_on_order_fills=true)
// Parameters
src                   = input("K"         , group="Indicator"           , title="Based on :", options=["K","D"]              )
length0               = input(11          , group="Indicator"           , title="%K length"                                  )
length1               = input(3           , group="Indicator"           , title="%K Smoothing"                               )
length2               = input(8           , group="Indicator"           , title="%D Smoothing"                               )
i_indicatorBuy        = input(35          , group="Indicator"           , title="Buy under: "                                )
b_media               = input(true        , group="EMA Filter"          , title="EMA Filter?"                                )
i_media               = input(72          , group="EMA Filter"          , title="Length?"                                    )
b_minOfLastCandles    = input(true        , group="Stop Rules"          , title="based on the minimum of the last X candles?")
i_minOfLastCandles    = input(2           , group="Stop Rules"          , title="How many?"                                  )
target                = input(2.0         , group="Strategy Rules"      , title="Target"                                     )
i_risk                = input(1           , group="Strategy Rules"      , title="Risk in % based on Total Capital"           )
b_betItAll            = input(true        , group="Strategy Rules"      , title="Reinvest all profit?"                       )
signalColor           = input(color.yellow, group="Color of the Candles", title="Signal Candle Color"                        )
entryColor            = input(color.lime  , group="Color of the Candles", title="Entry Candle Color"                         )

// Estrategy calculation formulas
minOfLastCandles = lowest(low,i_minOfLastCandles)
deltaCandle      = b_minOfLastCandles ? (high - minOfLastCandles) : (high - low)
longTarget       = high + deltaCandle * target
long_stopBuy     = high

// Stop formulas
long_stopLoss     = if b_minOfLastCandles
    long_stopLoss = minOfLastCandles[1]
if not b_minOfLastCandles    
    long_stopLoss := low    

// market position formulas
opened   = strategy.position_size[0] != 0 and strategy.position_size[1] == 0
inMarket = strategy.opentrades > strategy.opentrades[1]

// Target and Stop Verifier
checkLongBuy      = inMarket ?  long_stopBuy[1] : na
checkLongTarget   = inMarket ?  longTarget[1]   : na
checkLongstopLoss = inMarket ?  long_stopLoss   : na


// Risk Management formulas
long_stopLossRisk     = if b_minOfLastCandles
    long_stopLossRisk = minOfLastCandles
if not b_minOfLastCandles    
    long_stopLossRisk := low    
    
operationRisk = (long_stopLossRisk/long_stopBuy-1)*-1
risk = i_risk / 100
riskManagement = b_betItAll ? risk / operationRisk * strategy.equity : risk / operationRisk * strategy.initial_capital

maxQTY = riskManagement / long_stopBuy

//Indicador
periodK        = length0
smoothK        = length1
periodD        = length2
k              = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d              = sma(k, periodD)

// Indicator Check Formula
indicator      = if src == "K"
    indicator  = k
if src == "D"
    indicator := d
    
// Trend variables
bullishTrend = close > ema(close,i_media)
indicatorBuy = indicator < i_indicatorBuy

// Strategy
if b_media 
    if bullishTrend and indicatorBuy
        strategy.entry("Entry", strategy.long,qty=maxQTY, comment="Entry on Bullish Stoch", stop=long_stopBuy)
    if inMarket 
        strategy.exit("Exit","Entry",comment="Stoch Exit",limit=checkLongTarget, stop=long_stopLoss)
    if bullishTrend[2] and indicatorBuy[2] and not opened or bullishTrend[1] and not bullishTrend[0] or indicatorBuy[1] and not indicatorBuy[0]
        strategy.cancel("Entry",when=close)
    if strategy.closedtrades > strategy.closedtrades[1]
        strategy.cancel_all()
        
if not b_media
    if indicatorBuy
        strategy.entry("Entry", strategy.long,qty=maxQTY, comment="Entry", stop=high[1])
    if inMarket 
        strategy.exit("Exit","Entry",comment="Stoch Exit",limit=checkLongTarget, stop=long_stopLoss)
    if indicatorBuy[2] and not opened or indicatorBuy[1] and not indicatorBuy[0]
        strategy.cancel("Entry",when=close)
    if strategy.closedtrades > strategy.closedtrades[1]
        strategy.cancel_all()

//Plot the target and stop lines on the chart
valuewhen_Long        = valuewhen(bullishTrend and indicatorBuy, longTarget, 0)
valuewhen_Stop        = valuewhen(bullishTrend and indicatorBuy, long_stopLoss, 0)
valuewhen_Buy         = valuewhen(bullishTrend and indicatorBuy, long_stopBuy, 0)
valuewhen_checkTarget = valuewhen(checkLongTarget, longTarget[1], 0)
valuewhen_checkStop   = valuewhen(checkLongstopLoss, long_stopLoss, 0)

plot(strategy.opentrades != 0 ? valuewhen_checkTarget : na,style=plot.style_circles,color=color.lime,linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.opentrades != 0 ? valuewhen_checkStop   : na,style=plot.style_circles,color=color.red,linewidth=2)

plot(checkLongTarget,                    style=plot.style_circles, color=color.white ,linewidth=4)
plot(checkLongstopLoss,                  style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red   ,linewidth=4)
plot(b_media ? ema(close,i_media) : na , style=plot.style_line   , color=color.orange,linewidth=4)

//Plot signal Candles and Entry Candles on the chart
o = open
Open =  bullishTrend and indicatorBuy ? o : na
h = high
High =  bullishTrend and indicatorBuy ? h : na
l = low
Low =   bullishTrend and indicatorBuy ? l : na
c = close
Close = bullishTrend and indicatorBuy ? c : na

plotcandle(Open,High,Low,Close,"Signal Candle Color "  ,signalColor,signalColor,bordercolor=signalColor)
plotcandle(Open[1]  and inMarket ? open : na,High[1]  and inMarket ? high : na,Low[1]   and inMarket ? low : na,Close[1] and inMarket ? close : na,"Entry Candle Color",entryColor,entryColor,bordercolor=entryColor)
```

Examples:

1. https://www.tradingview.com/x/RUdODw4O/
2. https://www.tradingview.com/x/k8FEAGD6
3. https://www.tradingview.com/x/H7zRTxR0/

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround? I'm in the exact situation...

Answer (score 0):

> the purpose of leaving calc_on_order_fills true is that I want it to
> exit the trade if the target or stop is hit during the current
> candles.

The `calc_on_order_fills` purpose is force calculate the strategy immediately after order fill without waiting for bar close. The `strategy.exit` closes a  trade without any delay with `calc_on_order_fills=false` (by default) too.

Comment: the problem I'm encountering is that the output value is being at the candle's maximum, instead of the value I put at limit

Comment: like example 1, the exit value of the trade was supposed to be at 10470, but this value was substituted for the candle's high

Comment: Was the `example 1` calculated with `calc_on_order_fills=false`?

Comment: example 1 was calculated with ```calc_on_order_fills=true```, if I put ```calc_on_order_fills=false``` the result is this
https://www.tradingview.com/x/NtJ2MHoc/

Comment: the moment in question is 02/13/2020 at 12:00 UTC, at 2 hours timeframe